# Redmine REST API -client-server

Tags: html, css

My boss told me to create a REST API using html/css but i'm copletely blocked..
How can we create Redmine RESTful API using html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a REST API only with html. A REST API means that you defines a "resource" and you utilize the HTTP (usually) protocol in order to change the "state" of the resource. For example: the resource is http://example.com/a. You can make a GET request in order to get this resource, POST for changing it and DELETE for deleting it.

As you can see, it's a work with the server and not with the content that the client sees (html) - You need a server-side language, like: Python, Java, Php, etc.
Please tell us if you know a server-side language and we will be able to tell you how you can program a REST API in that language.

Comment: SO why there is GET and POST method in HTML forms ?

Comment: You can get access to the resources from the client side and even from the browser, but you can't define them from the client side.